# How to test angular async function which has await statement in the code block

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a simple function in angular using karma and jasmine.

> class

```
export class Acl {
  async caller() {
    console.log("first statement");
    const calledMe = await this.callMe().toPromise();
    return calledMe;
  }

  callMe() {
    return new Observable((observer) => observer.next({ something: "key" }));
  }
}
```

> test file

```
import { Acl } from "./main";
import { fakeAsync, tick } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

describe("Hello world", () => {
  it("test the async", fakeAsync(() => {
    const t = new Acl();
    spyOn(t, "callMe").and.returnValue(
      new Observable((observer) => observer.next({ something: "key" }))
    );

    const cl = t.caller();

    console.log("a print ", cl);
    tick();
  }));
});
```

the output for the print statement in the test case is 
[image]

How to test such functions.

Answer (score 1):

Your test should be made up of at least one expectation, else you aren't testing for a specific result but just that the code runs without errors.

In your case I think you could store the spy as a constant and then expect that it has been called after `tick`, like that:

```
describe("Hello world", () => {
  it("test the async", fakeAsync(() => {
    const t = new Acl();
    const spy = spyOn(t, "callMe").and.returnValue(
      new Observable((observer) => observer.next({ something: "key" }))
    );

    t.caller();
    tick();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
  }));
});
```

Comment: if I add expectation the thing remains the same.
the statements after the await do not get executed. I need to test statements after the await call
the code I have added is simplified version of what i am trying.

Answer (score 0):

The test shown in the other answer is correctly written and should work -- the `expect` statement should fire and pass.

If it's not passing, it could be due to [this Zone.js issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37742). If your tests are running as native `async/await` (target ES2017 or higher), Zone cannot hook your `await` statement, so `tick()` will not cause it to proceed.  You can test this by putting logging statements immediately before and after the `await` line and the `tick()` line:

```
  async caller() {
    console.log("before await");
    const calledMe = await this.callMe().toPromise();
    console.log("after await");
    return calledMe;
  }

  // ...

  it("test the async", fakeAsync(() => {
    const t = new Acl();
    const spy = spyOn(t, "callMe").and.returnValue(
      new Observable((observer) => observer.next({ something: "key" }))
    );

    t.caller();
    console.log("before tick");
    tick();
    console.log("after tick");

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
  }));
```

If you run this with `target: "es2015"` in your tsconfig, you should see "before await", "before tick", "after await", "after tick", then your test should pass.  If you run it with `target: "es2017"` or later, like 2018/2020/esnext, you should see "before await", "before tick", "after tick", then your test should fail, then "after await" will probably log after the test body function has totally finished executing.

As an aside, this drove me crazy for about 2 days.  Users of the `ng` CLI get a warning when they try to go past `es2015`, but not if you compile your project using the `AngularCompilerPlugin` webpack plugin directly, though [that should be fixed soon](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19226).